# Aurelia Typescript http-fetch-client async catch not working

Tags: typescript, error-handling, async-await, try-catch, aurelia

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or it simply does not work.

I have a service

```
export class Service {
    constructore(private http: HttpClient){}
    async delete(id:number){
        try{
            return this.http.fetch('api/deleteItem?id='+id,{method:'post'})
        } catch(error){
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
        }
    }
}
```

and the consummer is calling it like this:

```
async deleteItem(item){
    try{
        let result = await this.myService.delete(this.item.id);
        this.model.items.remove(item);
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Now, if the webapi service throw an exception, my catch block does not catch it. So it deletes it from the model.items although it shouldn't.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error.
I am using a http interceptor that does not handle error's from http, it just returns the response as json object.